# Printing Unix directory content as normal text file

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, operating-system

I'm very curious how unix system works, now I'm interested in directories which are collection of files, especially collection of two items like a name of file and index(number) to table of i-nodes for that file and I would like to know if there is any hack to print directory as normal text file to see directory content...

any ideas?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you mean by “print […] as normal text file”. The `readdir()` function and the `dirent` structure are probably where you should look at first.

Comment: I assume you want to get information about file/directory. Use `stat filename` or `stat directoryname`.

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/how-are-directories-implemented-in-unix-filesystems) over on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. Note that directories are typically not files on modern file systems.

Comment: ls -ai1 dir/ is something what I expected but I realized that I need something more dump, I want something like hexdump -C dir/ but this doesnt work, I need something where I can see structure of directory as it is in my HDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On older *nix systems you could invoke VI on directories and view the contents of the directory-file. Maybe still. Of course that would just load binary gibberish with here and there recognizable strings, and is not very usable.

So yes, directories are binary.  You can try to open a directory as a file for reading to read its contents, but the best solution to parse them is to use getdents (which is the primitive for the already mentioned readdir, readdir skips unused inodes and padding bytes though).

This is a very small abstraction layer (e.g. filesystem type!) that for *nix native filesystems is pretty close to the data on disk. Simply dumping the record fields in a readable format would give you a nice representation.

Some EXT*fs tools might already have such functionality ready to use, I suggest you look into that, most notably **debugfs**.

Comment: so if directories are binary, then linux_dirent structures are stored in directory files, ok but how? they are serialized? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html

Answer (score 0):

The [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command may may be what you're looking for.

e.g.

```
$ stat .
  File: ‘.’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 40         IO Block: 65536  directory
Device: 177383d6h/393446358d    Inode: 562949953432553  Links: 1
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (   18/  SYSTEM)   Gid: (   18/  SYSTEM)
Access: 2015-04-08 16:27:53.211425700 +0100
Modify: 2015-04-08 16:27:53.211425700 +0100
Change: 2015-04-08 16:27:53.211425700 +0100
 Birth: 2011-01-15 06:23:35.436641100 +0000
```

Comment: Stat shows metadata of the directory file, not its contents ?

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
ls /path/to/directory > file.txt
```

Also there's the tree utility that can print our a visually more appealing representation of the directory structure.

Comment: This doesn't even remotely answer the question.